# Variable "generator" on Python using other variables

Tags: python, variables, loops, for-loop, generator

I am wondering, if it is possible to create variables and name the using strings and other variables on Python. It would really help me on sth I'm making.

For example i want to create 10 variables:

```
var0
var1
var2
...
```

I have tried doing it with the "for" loop like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    'var'+str(i) = 0
```

but it gives me an error. Please help!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may think you want to do this, but you probably don't. Use a dictionary or a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to be using "variable variables". You want to use a dictionary:

```
>>> vars = {i:0 for i in range(10)}
>>> vars
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
```

Now you can access each element like this `var[6]` (and you're not limited to integers as dictionary keys, either: `var["yay!"] = "Great!"`).

Of course, for the special case of a range of 0 to 9, you can also simply use a list:

```
>>> vars = [0 for i in range(10)]
>>> vars
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: +1: Noting that for Python versions < 2.7 which don't have dictionary comprehensions the first example of creation would need to be something like `vars = dict((i,0) for i in xrange(10))` or perhaps `vars = dict.fromkeys(xrange(10), 0)`,

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a list, not a ton of variables:

```
>>> var = [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10]
>>> var[1]
2
>>> var [2]
5
>>>
```

My rule of thumb is that if more than three variables have similar names (`var1`, `var2` and `var3`, for example), put them in a list.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about lists!

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you can do:

```
for i in range(10):
    locals()['var' + str(i)] = 0

print var3
```

Comment: This is horrible.  Please don't recommend it.  And don't say, "I didn't say it was a good idea!"

Comment: That only works in global scope. From docs ( http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals ): "The contents of this [locals()] dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: Please explain why it is so "horrible".

Comment: @thebjorn: OK, change `locals()` to `globals()`.

Comment: It's "horrible" because (i) it doesn't work in a function, (ii) it's the wrong solution to a simple problem -- the accepted answer has the correct solution, and (iii) suggesting it, without any commentary, is a disservice to the OP.

Comment: @martineau: as others have pointed out, it doesn't work.  But even if it did, it's a long-winded way of making a list.  Chances are good that these number variables will have to be accessed in some general way, meaning later where they are read, we'll get another piece of complexity similar to this one.  Why not just use the data structures Python gives us to begin with?

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately is _does_ work, at least in CPython 2.7.3 (and in many earlier versions) despite the warning that it might not in the documentation. Even so, and while I agree that creating variables that differ only by a numeric suffix is very likely a poor way for the OP to solve their problem, I don't think that creating variables programmatically is _always_ a bad approach -- which is the impression given by many of the comments -- and so don't think that down-voting an answer that does it primarily for that reason is fair to the author.